# Termination function definition (algorithms)

Tags: algorithm, termination, invariants, loop-invariant

A question about the  definition of termination functions.

We  have a relatively simple function for calculating *⌊log₂ n⌋* of an input.

```
LOG2
Configuration: {[r, n] | Integers r ≥ 0 and n ≥ 1}
[r, n] -> [r + 1, n/2] if n > 1 ∧ n even
[r, n] -> [r, n − 1] if n > 1 ∧ n odd
```

And we  are  asked whether some termination functions *μ(r,n)* are  correct.

- *μ(r,n)= n* is correct: the function's end condition is when *n = 1*, as  at that point *r = ⌊log₂ n₀⌋*.
- However, *μ(r,n)=2n+r* is apparently also correct.
- Furthermore, *μ(r,n) =  n + r* is incorrect

It  was  my  understanding that the termination function *μ(r,n)* was  simply the variable that the functions termination was  dependent upon, (In this case  *n* reaching 1,) so why  is *2n+r* a termination function?

What  is the exact  definition of termination function *μ(r,n)*  in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The termination function *μ* must be positive for states where the loop is entered, and strictly decreasing by every iteration. That, plus the well-orderedness of natural numbers ensures that your loop will always terminate. (Note that there is no requirement that *μ(s) = 1* for *s* that exits the loop, just that it always decreases per iteration.)

The problem with choosing *μ(r,n) = n + r* is that for *n = 2*, we have

- *n* even
- *n > 1*

and so the transition `[r, n] -> [r + 1, n / 2]` is valid. However, in this case, we'd have

```
μ(r',n') =         Definition of r' and n'
μ(r+1,n/2) =       Definition of μ
r + 1 + n/2 =      Rearrange via n = 2
r + 2 = 
r + n =            Definition of μ
μ(r, n)
```

so *μ* doesn't strictly decrease.